# Having trouble with displaying boolean in Java

Tags: java, boolean, output

This is my first exercise with boolean. I need to display the output for car_Type whether it's a national car or imported car. The main class was already compiled successfully but when i run it and type in the input it says "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException". Here's the main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CarApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //declaration
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  String model, brand;
  double price;
  boolean type;
  
  Car c = new Car();
  
  System.out.println("Enter a car Model : ");//X70/Starex
  model = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("\nEnter a car Brand : ");//Proton/Hyundai
  brand = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println("\nEnter the car price : RM");//95000.00/170000.00
  price = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("\nEnter the car brand [national/imported] : ");//national/imported car
  type = input.nextBoolean();
     
  //output
  System.out.println("Car Model : "+model);

  }
}
```

Also, here's the car class if you want to check on the error:

```
public class Car
{
String car_Model;
String car_Brand;
double car_Price;
boolean car_Type;

public Car()
{
car_Model = " ";
car_Brand = " ";
car_Price = 0.0;
car_Type = true;
}

public Car(String cm, String cb, double cp, boolean ct)
{
car_Model = cm;
car_Brand = cb;
car_Price = cp;
car_Type = ct;
}

void SetCar_Model(String cm){
   car_Model = cm;
}
void SetCar_Brand(String cb){

 car_Brand = cb;
}
void SetCar_Price(double cp){
 car_Price = cp;
}
void SetCar_Type(boolean ct){
car_Type = ct;
}

String GetCar_Model()
{
return car_Model;
}
String GetCar_Brand()
{
return car_Brand;
}
double GetCar_Price()
{
  return car_Price;
}
Boolean GetCar_Type()
{
  return car_Type;
}
 public String toString()
{
  return "Car Model : " +car_Model + "\nCar Brand : " +car_Brand + "\nCar Price : " +car_Price + "Car Type : " +car_Type;
}
}
```

Here's the input:

```
Enter a car Model :
X70
Enter a car Brand :
Hyundai
Enter the car price : RM
95000.00
Enter the car brand [national/imported] : 
national
```

And after i click enter it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1893)
at CarApp.main(CarApp.java:23)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"and type in the input"* what are you typing exactly? Please [edit] your question to include a sample input.

Comment: `input.nextBoolean()` expects either `true` or `false` in the input, not a string like `national/imported`.

Answer (score 0):

Java **boolean** data type, can only take the values **true** or **false**.

Answer (score 0):

`national` can't be parsed as a boolean. You have to parse it yourself according to your logic. You could name the field for example `isNational` and set it to `true` if the user entered national and `false` if imported was entered. In your toString method you can then either return "imported" or "national" according to the boolean of `isNational` like so

```
isNational ? "national" : "imported"
```

this is called a [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator).

Also think about what should happen if the user enters neither one of those two choices.

You don't need to declare all your variables at the top of the method and then assign them below. Most of the time, if it's deterministic which value gets assigned you can assign it at the time of declaration.

And lastly: usually Java fields are written in [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). Take a look on Java naming conventions [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).